# Declare a case insensitive keyword with EBNF

Tags: keyword, case-insensitive, ebnf

I want to declare with EBNF notation a keyword, i.e. `switch`.

```
<keyword_switch> ::= "switch";
```

Is there a way to declare the keyword as case insensitive without declare all possible letters combination?

I think that the following declaration is correct (but unsire, I'm a newbie with EBNF):

```
<keyword_switch> ::= ("S"|"s")("W"|"w")("I"|"i")("T"|"t")("C"|"c")("H"|"h");
```

but it's not very readable. Is there another simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<keyword_switch> ::= ("S"|"s")("W"|"w")("I"|"i")("T"|"t")("C"|"c")("H"|"h");
```

seems to be ok with antlr --
http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2007-August/023267.html

Heretic as it may seem, I'd suggest

```
<keyword_switch> ::= "switch" | "Switch" | "SWITCH";
```

assuming that `sWitch` and `sWiTcH` etc. are hardly what a user would need.

Comment: But it will not be case insensitive. If there's no simple solution I'll maintain my code for real case insensitivity.

Comment: Yes, it won't. For real case insentivity, ANTLR, e.g., has [Aa] tokens or fragments -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/22160240/4007818

Comment: Marpa, on the other hand, has ":ic" and ":i" modifiers for real case-insensitivity -- https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Marpa-R2/pod/Scanless/DSL.pod#Single-quoted-strings